# VS 2010 addin for Fogbugz?

Tags: add-in, visual-studio-2010, fogbugz, fogbugz-on-demand

I'm starting a project in Visual Studio 2010 and I'd like to use FogBugz in conjunction with it, but the addin supplied appears to be for VS 2008. Is there a version that works with 2010?

[crosses fingers and hopes Joel answers ;)]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried asking at the [FogBugz Knowledge Exchange](http://fogbugz.stackexchange.com/)?  It's maintained by FogBugz users and Fog Creek employees, so they're your best bet into finding out if something like this exists.